# Linkedin V2 version API access

Tags: linkedin-api

We are using the V1 version of the LinkedIn API to share articles on LinkedIn Profile and company pages. As V1 API does not allow media upload capability, we are looking for V2 version API access. It seems V2 version is available to partners only.

We have tried becoming a LinkedIn partner by filling up the partner form but we do not get any reply back. We have done 4 attempts till now but still no luck.

We are running a social media scheduling tool where our customers share various type of articles, image, and video posts but because of not having the V2 API access, we are not able to offer media sharing/scheduling features to our customers.

Can anyone guide or help us to get the V2 API access?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you ever able to get access? I'm interested in the shares/"Community Management" API but was told they only accept applications for Ad Tech, Marketing Analytics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive a reply from them but it take a while (we received it in about a month)